# How calculate the features' influence on prediction NN?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, neural-network, keras

There are about 20 features in my data and I wonder if there is any way to check how each column influences the final prediction. For example if it has negative impact on prediction, it will be better to get rid of it.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow
Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add your non working code snippet

Comment: Hi thank you! My code works well, the question is not about fixing not working code.

Answer (score 0):

sklearn has the [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) that has the **property** `feature_importances_`

I also want to know the answer. Maybe this can help us.

Comment: you also can go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/46132850/7194271